# MongoDB skip & limit when querying two collections

Tags: mongodb, limit, skip

Let's say I have two collections, A and B, and a single document in A is related to N documents in B. For example, the schemas could look like this:

```
Collection A:
{id: (int),
 propA1: (int),
 propA2: (boolean)
}
Collection B:
{idA: (int), # id for document in Collection A
 propB1: (int),
 propB2: (...),
 ...
 propBN: (...)
}
```

I want to return properties `propB2-BN` and `propA2` from my API, and only return information where (for example) `propA2 = true`, `propB6 = 42`, and `propB1 = propA1`.

This is normally fairly simple - I query Collection B to find documents where `propB6 = 42`, collect the `idA` values from the result, query Collection A with those values, and filter the results with the Collection A documents from the query.

However, adding skip and limit parameters to this seems impossible to do while keeping the behavior users would expect. Naively applying skip and limit to the first query means that, since filtering occurs after the query, less than limit documents could be returned. Worse, in some cases no documents could be returned when there are actually still documents in the collection to be read. For example, if the limit was 10 and the first 10 Collection B documents returned pointed to a document in Collection A where `propA2 = false`, the function would return nothing. Then the user would assume there's nothing left to read, which may not be the case.

A slightly less naive solution is to simply check if the return count is < limit, and if so, repeat the queries until the return count = limit. The problem here is that skip/limit queries where the user would expect exclusive sets of documents returned could actually return the same documents.

I want to apply skip and limit at the mongo query level, not at the API level, because the results of querying collection B could be very large.

[MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) and the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) appear to only work on a single collection, so they don't appear to be alternatives.

This seems like something that'd come up a lot in Mongo use - any ideas/hints would be appreciated.

Note that [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040592/how-to-use-limit-operator-on-two-collections-in-mongodb) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067464/mongodb-join-like-query-with-two-collections-and-a-where-clause) ask similar sounding questions but don't actually address the issues raised here.

Comment: what exactly do you want to limit?

Comment: The number of documents returned to the user.

Comment: I have the same problem, what was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already have a solution (2).

You cannot optimize/skip/limit on first query, depending on search you can perhaps do it on second query.

You will need a loop around it either way, like you write.

I suppose, the .skip will always be costly for you, since you will need to get all the results and then throw them away, to simulate the skip, to give the user consistent behavior.

All the logic would have to go to your loop - unless you can match in a clever way to second query (depending on requirements).

Out of curiosity: Given the time passed, you should have a solution by now?!

Comment: No, I don't think there is a solution to this problem that preserves the skip/limit semantics. Since skip/limit aren't scalable anyway, the real solution is not to use them.